# Using the composite design pattern to operate on objects of different type, is there a way to prevent an object from being operated on more than once?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, composite

I'd like to use the Composite design pattern in C++ to be able to create and operate on groups of objects. A problem I've encountered is that since leaves and composites are treated the same, and composites can be comprised of leaves and composites, it is quite possible for an object to be operated on more than once when a command is issued to a composite.

For example, a composite group1 contains objects A and B. Then, a composite group2 is created containing composite group1 and object A. When composite group2 is operated on, object A will be operated on twice. For some applications I guess this isn't a problem, but for my uses I'd like it if, for any command issued to a composite, unique objects are only operated on once.

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this problem, either some how preventing multiple calls of an object's member function, or preventing an object from being included in a composite more than once?

--

Update: 
By "idiomatic" I mean "traditional" or "accepted" way of handling this type of problem.
I guess I'm just assuming/hoping this is a common problem that has an established solution.

Comment: Your problem is that object A has two 'parents', what are you trying to achieve here?  Why is this object in two groups?  If it has to be, then the standard idea of applying an operation isn't going to work as you expected.  You'd have to somehow keep track of what objects you performed 'this' operation on and only perform on an object if you haven't.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is the flexibility of groups to be created not just from individual objects but from any combination of objects and existing groups--basically what the Composite pattern is for, right, being able to treat leaves and composites the same through the component interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by idiomatic, but a solution would depend on how yo traverse the structure of composites. Here are some options

- if you use a visitor and remember the already visited components, ignore duplicates
- use a tick count and have the composite element ignore successive calls with the same tick count
- in a two step method gather all the composite objects that need to be operated on in a set and then perform your operation
- in a two step method set a flag in your composite objects that signifies when they have been touched this round, clear the flag before the next round

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try the flag method. Just wondering, though, is this type of problem (not wanting multiple calls of an object's member functions) not commonly associated with the Composite pattern? I feel like it has to be. Or is the Composite pattern normally used for applications where this doesn't matter? Is there a better design pattern I should use if I want to ensure only one function call per object?